# How can I use Spring bean in abstract class

Tags: java, spring, abstract-class

The abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T> {

    abstract void doSomeThing;

}
```

that extends class

```
@Component
public class AServiceImpl<Entity> extends AbstractService<Entity> {

}
```

that I want to use

```
public class RestfullController {

    @Resource
    AbstractService abstractService;

}
```

but the note is

```
Description:

A component required a bean of type 'com.test.AbstractService' that could not be found.
```

How can I use this extends class?

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor injection instead of @Resource

- RestfullController

```
@RestController
public class RestfullController {

    AbstractService abstractService;

    public RestfullController(AbstractService abstractService) {
        this.abstractService = abstractService;
    }

}
```

- AbstractService

```
public abstract class AbstractService {

    abstract void doSomeThing();

}
```

- AServiceImpl

```
@Component
public class AServiceImpl extends AbstractService {

    @Override
    void doSomeThing() {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Hope it will helps you :)

Comment: thank you，my springboot version is 1.4.7.RELEASE，you method is not work

Comment: Ok, edited my answer, instead of @Autowired you can use constructor injection. Spring will automatically pass AbstractService bean as parameter to constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `AServiceImpl` directly in your controller or declare an interface instead of abstract class, since the last one can't be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

You can declare **AbstractService abstractService** and init constructor on **RestfullController** with parameter **AbstractService**. Spring will auto init component when start.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the application cannot scan the component,
please check if you added `@ComponentScan` in your main application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
// ...
```